# How can I add a transparent OS X style border to an image using command line tools?

Tags: linux, image, unix, image-processing, sips

I have images and want to add a transparent gradient background to them, similar to the way OS X does with window shadows.

Is there a way I can use something like `mogrify` or `sips` to add this border? The images I want to process are not screenshots, but let me show two screenshots so the effect I'm attempting is clear:

Flat image:

[image: Picture.png]

With transparent gradient:

[image: Picture 1.png]

This doesn't have to be exactly the same, just something similar and not a solid square border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you say "something similar" is also accepted. try the command below:

```
kent$  convert yourPNG.png \( +clone -background black -shadow 50x15+9+15 \) +swap -background none -mosaic +repage new.png
```

you need have [Imagemagic](http://www.imagemagick.org) installed.

the result looks like this:

[image]

**updated**

hope this time it meets your need

```
kent$  convert yourPng.png \( +clone -background black -shadow 55x15+0+5 \) +swap -background none -layers merge  +repage new.png
```

result:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the top and left are clipped. How do you fix that?

Comment: You can add a transparent border using border and bordercolor options, like so:
convert pic.png \( +clone -background black -shadow 50x15+9+15 \) +swap -bordercolor none -border 40 -background none -mosaic +repage new.png

Comment: Hey @Kent - what is the `55x15+0+5` syntax? blur, offset, and transparency?